# AppViewBackButtonVisibility not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to show a "back" button on my (Xamarin.Forms) UWP app when running on a desktop PC. I'm running the following code in the `App`'s `OnLaunched` method:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```

But the back button is not shown.

The line *does* work on a pure UWP app. But not in Xamarin.Forms.

Is there any additional step needed to get this working?

**EDIT**

It seems now that when navigating to a new `NavigationPage(page)` instead of just the page - that's what creates this problem. Am checking it now.

Comment: You need to use MainPage=new NavigationPage(new rootPage). Then use Navigation.PushAsync and PopAsync to get that Back button shown and hidden automatically

Comment: @YuriS Perfect! You can transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
MainPage=new NavigationPage(new rootPage).
```

Then use `Navigation.PushAsync` and `PopAsync` to get that Back button shown and hidden automatically