# Can't edit LaunchScreen.storyboard on Visual Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, app-store, visual-studio-2017

I have a Xamarin.Forms app, and am trying to publish the iOS app in it. I'm following the [Xamarin tutorial here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/) for the launch screen.

In steps 6 and 7 it assumes there is [some View on the screen](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/Images/Launch01vs.png). I don't see one. This is what I have:

[image]

When I try to drag an Image View as mentioned in the tutorial - I get a "do not enter" symbol on the Image View. (I assume, because I first need the default View there.)

What now? (I'm using VS2017 on Windows 10 Pro.)

Comment: just add ViewController and go from there

Comment: @YuriS Perfect! (Again.) You can transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add ViewController and go from there

Comment: Thanks. Don't forget you can write an answer to my other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661275/appviewbackbuttonvisibility-not-working) as well.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Where do I create the view controller, and how is it connected to LaunchScreen.storyboard, etc.?

Comment: @jbyrd You cannot add just ImageView, you need controller in storyboard to add ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop ViewController to LaunchScreen.storyboard

Example here:

[image]